# Problema ao colocar uma imagem de background em apenas uma view

Tags: css, angularjs, background

Tenho um pequeno sistema em Angular onde tenho uma tela de login:
Porém quando tento colocar uma imagem de background o resultado não é o esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="background">
../Código da página
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background{
  background: url(nature.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover; /*Css padrão*/
  -webkit-background-size: cover; /*Css safari e chrome*/
  -moz-background-size: cover; /*Css firefox*/
  -ms-background-size: cover; /*Css IE não use mer#^@%#*/
  -o-background-size: cover; /*Css Opera*/
}
```

Essa página de login é renderizada através do `ng-view` que fica em uma `div` no meu `index.html`:

index.html:

```
<body>
   <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Se eu coloco a minha classe `CSS` que é responsável pela imagem de background no `body`, dessa forma: `<body class="background">` funciona perfeitamente, mas quando tento coloca-la em uma `div` direto na página fica com os espaços em branco, como resolvo esse problema?

Comment: Pode criar um [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @renan até poderia, mas não sei se tem como usar o ng-view no fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução mais simples seria atribuir a propriedade CSS [`background-image`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) diretamente na tag `body`.

Como você tem interesse em definir um *background* específico para sua *view* de login, uma das formas mais simples seria trabalhar com variáveis de controle para alterar/adicionar uma classe na tag `body`. Uma das opções nesse caso é utilizar a diretiva [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). Segue um exemplo:

```
<body ng-class="{login: variavelDeControle}">
```

Com a classe adicionada ao elemento, basta fazer um seletor específico para alterar o background:

```
body.login {
    background-image: url('endereco-da-imagem.png');
}
```

Para atribuir a imagem de *background* utilizando o `div.background`, conforme código que você compartilhou, vamos precisar alterar o estilo de vários elementos. São eles:

```
[1] body > [2] div[ng-view] > [3] div.background
```

O problema é que nenhum desses elementos possui uma altura definida, então você vai precisar atribuir a altura da página em cada um deles. Resumindo seria algo como:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body > div[ng-view] {
    height: 100%;
}

.background {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Preparei um [`plunker de exemplo`](http://plnkr.co/edit/hv3SyX0N5KLGn8bQtjTB) para auxiliar na sua implementação.

Comment: Sua solução ajustou a imagem porém ainda tem dois espaços em branco em cima e embaixo:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/GCgfH.jpg

Comment: Você tem como mandar uma screenshot com o console de desenvolvedor aberto pra gente ver melhor o HTML?

Comment: Pronto: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XsnTp.png

Comment: Esse cabeçalho está dentro da `div.background`? Vamos precisar do resto do HTML pra resolver o problema.

Comment: Sim, a div.background é a primeira div da página de login, depois eu chamo a página de login através do ng-view

Comment: @Techies editei a solução! Dá uma olhada depois!

Comment: Beleza, já vou fazer um teste.

Comment: Funcionou @Romulo, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer da seguinte forma:

CSS:

```
html,body{ height: 100%; }
.background{
   height: 100%;
   background: url(nature.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
   background-size: cover; /*Css padrão*/
   -webkit-background-size: cover; /*Css safari e chrome*/
   -moz-background-size: cover; /*Css firefox*/
   -ms-background-size: cover; /*Css IE não use mer#^@%#*/
   -o-background-size: cover; /*Css Opera*/
}
```